# How to create relations automaticly in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Is there a way to create relations automatically?

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = INNODB;


CREATE TABLE `profile` (`id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, `user_id` BIGINT, `photo` VARCHAR(255), INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id`), PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = INNODB;


ALTER TABLE `profile` ADD CONSTRAINT `profile_user_id_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

When I generate model via gii, it does not Build Relations.

Answer (score 0):

First create the relation in your database by adding foreign keys on the fields you wish. If you let Gii create a model after you've done this, it should recognize the foreign keys and it will add the relations, based on the foreign keys you set up, to the model.

If it doesn't, please post your model, after you created it with Gii.

Comment: I have already add relation, it doesn't work.
ALTER TABLE `profile` ADD CONSTRAINT `profile_user_id_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: Can you post your model? Which is created by Gii?

Answer (score 0):

Create relations in among your table in db. Make sure primary and foreign keys are properly defined. Once your DB is ready, use gii tool to create your models and it will automatically create the relations. Make sure to check though, as sometimes it messes up the relations, especially 1:n, n:n relations and you may have to do a bit of edit (but mots of the times it will work correctly. Also, if you are using mysql make sure table engine is innodb or else relations won't work.